# How to get a number of items from an array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

am stuck trying to limit the amount of array items displayed in a div at a time. pls help.

here is the problem.
i have a div:

```
<div id="site_list">
    <a href="#" id="0">Site 0</a>
    <a href="#" id="1"> Site 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="2"> Site 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="3"> Site 3</a>
    <a href="#" id="4"> Site 4</a>
    <a href="#" id="5"> Site 5</a>
    <a href="#" id="6"> Site 6</a>
    <a href="#" id="7">Site 7</a>
    <a href="#" id="8"> Site 8</a>
    <a href="#" id="9""> Site 9</a>
    <a href="#" id="10"> Site 10</a>
</div>
```

previous button

```
<button id="previous"> << Previous</button>
```

next button

```
<button id="next"> Next >> </button>
```

----- array of links --------

```
var link_array=$('#site_list a');
```

---

Links inside the "site_list" div can be updated dynamically, i want to be able to display only 5 links at a time so that when the "next" button is clicked, five more links will be displayed in the place of previously displayed content or if the remaining links are not up to five, then the remaining number of links hidden will be displayed, and if there is no links ahead, the "next" button will be hidden. this same process should take place when the "previous" button is clicked but in this case previous links will be displayed.

Please, i will appreciate your assistance.

Comment: `var link_array=$('#site_list a');` is that all you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a flexible way to do, change `current_range` to choose your starting point and change `per_page` to display more or less result per page.

Here is a <kbd>[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/Rnz49/)</kbd>

```
var current_range = 0;
var per_page = 5;
$('button').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is('#next')) {
        if (current_range <= $('#site_list a').length) current_range += per_page;
    } else if($(this).is('#previous')) {
        if (current_range > 0) current_range -= per_page;
    }
    change_view();
});

function change_view() {
    $('#site_list a').hide();
    $($('#site_list a').splice(current_range, per_page)).show();
}
change_view();
```

Comment: thanks do much, this was very useful. the only problem i have with it now is that i need to hide the next and previous buttons when there is nothing ahead or behind. please show me how to achieve this

Comment: and please i need to add a slide effect to enhance it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you need something like this:

```
$("#previous").on("click", "", function(event) {
  $("#site_list a:gt(5)").hide();
  $("#site_list a:lt(6)").show();
});

$("#next").on("click", "", function(event) {
  $("#site_list a:gt(5)").show();
  $("#site_list a:lt(6)").hide();
});
```

That will basically switch between first 5 links and last 5 links.
Also, if you give a bit more clear explanation - I will be able to prepare a draft jsfiddle, but just not sure if my answer is really what you need.